# Authenticate Restful service through Azure ACS with Google as an identity provider

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, azure, acs

I have developed Restful services using ServiceStack and deployed it onto on-premise (public facing URL) server. For authentication, I have configured Azure ACS with Google and Microsoft Live Id as identity providers.

I want to develop some back-end process where I will hit the above services and consume the data. I will not have any user interface to ask user for the credential as it will be executing in the back-end server. However, I will (of course) have legitimate credential, either Google or Live id.

Now, How can I authenticate using available user credential and consume those services through the code?

EDIT: Actually, I want to develop a dynamic client where one can register their service along with the credential that can be authenticated through ACS and consume the services. Saying that, I will have to call the service with supplied credential only. I cannot establish trusted relationship between back-end server and services.

Answer (score 0):

One option what you can do is following -

1. Use ACS Service Identities to build trust between your frontend and backend.
2. Once trust is established, you can pass user claims as just a part of payload from frontend to backend.

Alternatively you can use Poor Man Delegation described by WIF Guru Vittorio Bertocchi - http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas/

A More proper way to do is to go for ActAs mechanism, ActAs has been explained in the above resource which I shared,

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement is little different. I cannot establish the trusted relationship. To elaborate the question, I have just modified it. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Have you looked at the Poor Man Delegation, the Resource which I shared. It does the claims delegation exactly you want. When you do a poor man delegation, you will get both claims and at the same time you can authenticate the service which called the backend. If you are looking for your backend service go and talks to identity provider, then that is not what you get by default with ACS. You need to write your own STS.